# Glyphicon issue on alternating row disapears

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a table which binds its data via Angular. I am tasked with adding a pencil glyphicon to each row to show that the row is editable. The problem I am running into is if I use the bootstrap table-striped class and add the glyphicon glyphicon-pencil class it seems like the row is sitting behind the glyphicon the problem with this is the entire row is clickable but the glyphicon. If I add a style="z-index:-1" the pencil only shows up on the white rows and not the gray ones? I have fought and tried just bout everything I can think of and I cannot seem to get the glyphicon to show on the alternating rows using the z-index which does make the glyphicon clickable. Everything in the row above needs to be clickable. ( I need to be able to click on the pencil and or the grid and have it pass to the next view. )

Can someone help explain how I might be able to make this work correctly? Explain what might be happening?  I am totally at a loss at this point.

here is my html code

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="container" ng-hide="editing" style="margin-top:25px;">
     <div class="row">
            <div id="no-more-tables">
                <table ng-show="test.length > 0" class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
                    <thead style="text-align:left">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 27px;"></th>
                            <th>Field 1</th>
                            <th>Field 2</th>
                            <th>Field 3</th>
                            <th>Field 4</th>
                            <th>Field 5</th>
                            <th>Field 6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="{{test.guidfield}}" ng-repeat="testing in test" ng-click="edit($event)" style="cursor:pointer">
                            <td><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="z-index:-1"></div></td>
                            <td data-title="Field 1"> {{test.field1}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Field 2">{{test.field2}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Field 3">{{test.field3}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Field 4">{{test.field4}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Field 5">{{test.field5}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Field 6">{{test.field16}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the css I have

```
  /* ------- this media query makes tables display vertically on devices 768px or less  ------ */

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    #no-more-tables table, #no-more-tables thead, #no-more-tables tbody, #no-more-tables th,
    #no-more-tables td, #no-more-tables tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #no-more-tables thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    #no-more-tables tr {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #no-more-tables td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 60%;
        white-space: normal;
        text-align: right;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #no-more-tables td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    /*  Label the data  */
    #no-more-tables td:before {
        content: attr(data-title);
    }

    .table-bordered {
        border: none;
    }
```

Comment: A negative `z-index` will put an element further back, try a large number?

Comment: Oddly if I remove the table-strip and do the z-index of -1 it will work. Issue is I need to have the alternating row as well. If I do z-index of any positive number it does not work? i even went to 999 nothing :( any other suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a jsFiddle would be useful here.

Comment: Look at this bootply, what is the problem here? http://www.bootply.com/QKDLDzuveq

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="z-index:1"></i></td>
```

Comment: your question is long and confussing! what you want short and simple! Ask again if not solved! i am here!

Comment: I did try using the <i> tag and had not luck... Just tried your suggestion and I still have the same issue... Pencil is not clickable ? It's so weird :(

Comment: the short and simple is I need to be able to click on the pencil currently if you click on the pencil it does nothing.

Comment: @gbeford In this DEMO I can click on pencil. you can see the click event triggered. http://jsbin.com/gukokase/1/edit

Comment: hummm I wonder if it's a ui-bootstrap issue ( Angular )... I will see if I can get a demo up to show the weirdness I am experiencing.

Comment: Thank you all, for some really strange reason if I make a simple app it seems to work just fine... https://corker-chisel.codio.io/Table.html Not exactly sure what might be causing the issue... but I wanted to put a sample up

Answer (score 0):

I did discover that there is something in the ng-click causing this to not work. Thank you all for the help :)